# Having problems comparing strings (PHP)

Tags: php

My goal is to check if the value of the "token" stored in a cookie is the same as the value in the loginTable table in the db.
I am able to save the value of the cookie in the variable $token. The problem I have is here --> if ($row["token"] == $token). For example the value of the $token is bm0h8sdigs and the value in the row is bm0h8sdigs, but it does not enter the if. I also tried strcmp function but it didn't work. if(strcmp($row["token"], $token) == 0) I also tried $sqlToken = "select * from loginTable where token='" . $token . "'"; but it does not work.

echo $token; prints what is in my cookie - bm0h8sdigs

```
<!-- https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie This is a library to make handling cookies easier -->
<script>
   var token = Cookies.get('token');
</script>

<?php
   $token = "<script>document.write(token)</script>";

   $var = 0;
   include "connectDB.php";
                                
   $sqlToken = "SELECT * FROM loginTable";
   $resultToken = $mysqli->query($sqlToken);

   while($row = $resultToken->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($row["token"] == $token){
            $var = 1;
        }
   }
   $mysqli->close();
                                
   if ($var == 1){
   //Token found in db
   }
   else{
   //Token not found in db
   }
?>
```

connectDB.php

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "usbw";
    $database = "test";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $mysqli -> set_charset("utf8");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; 
    }
?>
```

loginTable - prnt.sc/u7nidn

```
Create table loginTable(
    loginID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID int not null,
    token varchar(20) not null,
    Constraint PK_loginTable Primary Key(loginID),
    Constraint FK_loginTable_userID Foreign Key (userID) References usersTable (userID)
)
```

Comment: can I see a screenshot of the value that is stored in your database table?

Comment: above the comparison line do `var_dump($row["token"], $token);` to see if this really matches. Also why not SELECT * WHERE token = :token insead of fetching all and comparing?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/u7nidn

Comment: I have put above da comparison line and the result is this :Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. I also tried $sqlToken =  "select * from loginTable where token='" . $token . "'"; but it does not work, i know it does the same job.

Comment: echo $token; prints what is in my cookie - bm0h8sdigs

Comment: Using `:token` would be a prepared statement utilizing `PDO`, not `mysqli`. Which is most likely why you got the `fetch_assoc() on a non-object` error, since the query bailed. You can see more errors by adding to the top of your script: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided shows that `$token` holds the value `<script>document.write(token)</script>;`
Of course comparison will fail then.

Your approach of passing the javascript variable to php will not work.
php has no acces to the javascript scope. Try passing your variable via `form` submit or try to access the cookie values directly in php, via `$_COOKIE`